# Simular un juego por turnos - penales - en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy tratando de desarrollar un simulador de penales, en el cual necesito un sistema de turnos que seria = (jugador, pc, jugador, pc....) pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo.

```
player1Score = 0
pcScore = 0
matchEnd = False

def printNet(Net):
    print('-------------------------------------')
    print('|  1   |          2           |   3  |')
    print('|----------------------------------- |')
    print('|      |                      |      |')
    print('|  4   |          5           |   6  |')
    print('|----------------------------------- |')
    print('|      |                      |      |')
    print('|   7  |          8           |   9  |')

def shooting(player1Score):
    import random
    notGoal = random.choice(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
    user = input ("Seleccione a donde desea tirar")
    if notGoal == user :
        player1Score += 0
        print ("No has anotado")
    else :
        player1Score += 1
        print("GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL")

def goalkeeping(pcScore):
    import random
    notGoal = random.choice(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6,7,8,9 )
    user = input("Seleccione a donde cree que ira el penalty")
    if notGoal == user:
        pcScore += 0
        print ("Lo has parado")
    else:
        pcScore += 1
        print ("Mala suerte, tu oponente ha anotado")


def matchEnd(player1Score,pcScore):
    if player1Score >= 5 & pcScore >= 5:
        matchEnd = True
    else: matchEnd = False
```

Esto es lo que llevo hasta ahora, cualquier otra recomendacion es aceptada, Gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Para la parte de las rondas, se haría dentro de un bucle infinito `while True` y por cada semi-ronda se verifica si el equipo ha ganado, ha perdido, o si aún siguen las rondas. Si resulta los dos primeros casos, se rompe el ciclo y se declara al ganador. Pseudocódigo:

```
equipo1, equipo2 = seleccionar_aleatoriamente([Equipo1], [Equipo2])
ciclo_infinito:
    patea el equipo1
    verificar si equipo1 ganó (True) o perdió (False)
        Asignar ganador
        romper ciclo_infinito (break)
    Patea el equipo2
    verificar si equipo2 ganó (True) o perdió (False)
        Asignar ganador
        romper ciclo_infinito (break)
    Si ambas verificaciones son [None], repetir el ciclo (siguiente tanda)
```

Mi propuesta es que cada equipo sea un [objeto](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) de una **clase** `Penales` para poder interactuar más fácil con sus métodos y atributos. Cada equipo es una lista `[nombre, tipo]` donde el primer elemento es el nombre (usuario, país...) y el segundo es el tipo de jugador (entrada_manual, CPU). El programa solo procesa el equipo automáticamente cuando ve la palabra "CPU", cualquier otra cosa la toma como entrada manual.

La función `check_winner()` no forma parte de la clase y evalúa si un equipo ganó. Primero lo hace en base a `limit = 5` en ronda regular y luego `6, 7, ... etc` en muerte súbita.

```
import random

class Penales:
    target = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
    def __init__(self, team):
        self.name = team[0]
        self.ttype = team[1]
        self.goals = []
        
    def human_select(self, msg):
        while True:
            h_inp = input(msg)
            if h_inp in self.target:
                break
        return h_inp
        
    def goalkeeping(self, rname, rtype):
        if rtype.upper() == 'CPU':
            rtarget = random.choice(self.target)
        else:
            rtarget = self.human_select(f'Arquero [{rname}] - Seleccione la dirección: ')
        return rtarget
        
    def shooting(self, rival, rival_type):
        if self.ttype.upper() == 'CPU':
            starget = random.choice(self.target)
        else:
            starget = self.human_select(f'Pateador [{self.name}] - Seleccione la dirección: ')
        # Verificar si fue gol o no
        rtarget = self.goalkeeping(rival, rival_type)
        print(f'Pateador ({self.name}): {starget} | Arquero ({rival}): {rtarget}', end="")
        if starget == rtarget:
            print(' | No anotó')
            self.goals.append(0)
        else:
            print(' | GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL')
            self.goals.append(1)
        
    def show_goals(self, align):
        gstring = ''
        for value in self.goals:
            gstring += 'G ' if value == 1 else 'x '
        if len(self.goals) < 5:
            gstring += '. ' * (5 - len(self.goals))
        return f'{self.name} [{gstring}]' if align == 'L' else f'[{gstring}] {self.name}'
    
def check_winner(cur_team_goals, riv_team_goals, i):
    limit = 5 if i <= 5 else i
    cscored = sum(cur_team_goals)
    cremain = limit - len(cur_team_goals)
    rscored = sum(riv_team_goals)
    rremain = limit - len(riv_team_goals)
    if cscored > rscored + rremain:
        win = True
    elif(rscored > cscored + cremain):
        win = False
    else:
        win = None
    return win
    
print('######## SIMULADOR DE PENALES ########\n')
teams = [['Argentina', 'Human'], ['Alemania', 'CPU']]
print('- Resultado del volado de moneda -')
random.shuffle(teams)
team1 = Penales(teams[0])
team2 = Penales(teams[1])
print(f'Primero en patear: {team1.name}. Segundo: {team2.name}\n')
i = 1
while True:
    if i == 1:
        print('=== TANDA REGULAR ===')
    elif i == 6:
        print('=== MUERTE SUBITA ===')
    print(f'{team1.show_goals("L")} - {team2.show_goals("R")}\n')
    print(f'[ Ronda {i} ]')
    team1.shooting(team2.name, team2.ttype)
    if (result := check_winner(team1.goals, team2.goals, i)) is not None:
        winner = team1.name if result else team2.name
        break
    team2.shooting(team1.name, team1.ttype)
    if (result := check_winner(team2.goals, team1.goals, i)) is not None:
        winner = team2.name if result else team1.name
        break
    i += 1
    print()

print('\nResultado Final')
print(f'{team1.show_goals("L")} - {team2.show_goals("R")}\n')
print(f'Ganador: {winner}')
```

[ * ] Puedes poner ambos equipos como CPU, y la computadora **¡jugará contra si misma!**

Un ejemplo de una simulación CPU vs CPU:

```
- Resultado del volado de moneda -
Primero en patear: Alemania. Segundo: Argentina

=== TANDA REGULAR ===
Alemania [. . . . . ] - [. . . . . ] Argentina

[ Ronda 1 ]
Pateador (Alemania): 2 | Arquero (Argentina): 1 | GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL
Pateador (Argentina): 8 | Arquero (Alemania): 1 | GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL

Alemania [G . . . . ] - [G . . . . ] Argentina
.
.
.
[ Ronda 5 ]
Pateador (Alemania): 7 | Arquero (Argentina): 4 | GOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOL

Resultado Final
Alemania [G G G G G ] - [G G x G . ] Argentina

Ganador: Alemania
```

Obviamente esta es una tanda de penales *ideal*, para que sea un poco más realista hay más trabajo que hacer, por ejemplo, agregar un chance de botar el disparo; agregar un pequeño porcentaje de que el arquero adivine la trayectoria independiente del valor aleatorio generado, y así bajar la probabilidad de acierto como a 75% - 80%. 
Como está actualmente he tenido tandas de muerte súbita hasta de 20 rondas, pero al menos te servirá como referencia.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!!!

Comment: @nicolasosoriobustos qué bien que te haya servido. Si la respuesta soluciona tu problema puedes [marcarla como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). De esta forma ayudarás a mejorar la reputación de esta pregunta en la comunidad.